# use the value of variables from a function from the first class in an another function from the second class

Tags: java, function, class, variables

I have two classes , I want to use the value of variables/String from a function  from the first class in an another   function  from the second class , for example :
In this case I want to use the value of String english and String frensh from FisrtFunction include in FirstClass , in the SecondFunction include in SecondClass , please help to fix that code because it's didn't read those values

```
public class FirstClass {
  public void FirstFunction() {
    String french;
    String english;
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
      String line;        
      while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
               String[] pair = line.split(";");
               french=(pair[0]);
               english=(pair[1]);  
      }
    }
  }
}

public class SecondClass {
  public void SecondFunction extends FirstClass () {
    int i=0;   
    boolean bool=true;    
    String reponce;
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr); 

    while (i<nbquest && bool) {
      System.out.println("donner la traduction de "+french);
      String reponseee  = in.readLine();     
      traduction = reponseee;  

      if(bool == true ) { 
        if(traduction.equals(english)) {
          score++;
          abc++;
          System.out.println("Bravo! Bonne reponse");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Mauvaise reponse");
          abc++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to read about basics of Java before trying to write code like this... Nevertheless, define your first class like this:

```
public class FirstClass {
    protected String french;
    protected String english;

    public void FirstFunction() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
...
}
```

This will make class members, not local variables of the method, available to the inherited class keeping them not visible for external classes.

I am sure you will have further questions to ask after you solve this one as there are many more issues with your code than this.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to access the values of objects created in a method outside of that method. The objects only exist in that method. Even within the same class (`FirstClass`), any method outside of `FirstFunction()` cannot simply use the value of Strings `french` and `english`.

If you want to be able to access the variables outside of the method, make them `public` or `protected` class instance variables, as in:

```
public class FirstClass {
  public String french;
  public String english;
  public void FirstFunction() {
    ....
```

However, their values will be null unless you call `FirstFunction()` before calling `SecondFunction()`

Comment: `public`, are you sure?

Comment: Either is fine, as I mention above the code

Comment: Well, either will work, but not really either is fine.

Comment: *"It's impossible to access the values of objects created in a method outside of that method."* This is not strictly true. It's only the case if there are no more references to these objects once the method terminates, in which case they will be garbage collected. However, a reference to such an object can easily last beyond the scope of a method.

Comment: I don't get this. If it's created within the method, once the method terminates how can there be references to it?

Comment: @asaini007 `foo() {Object o = new Object(); someGlobalVar = o;}`.

Comment: @arshajii Can't call `o` outside of the method, is what I meant - not the value. If `new Object()` is the value, what's the name for `o`?

Comment: @asaini007 `o` is just a *name*. The actual object is what it *points to*.